# Custom xticks labels on a bar chart (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization

Im trying to plot the 95% confidence interval for the mean on a bar chart. 
The bar colors are set based on the horizontal line value. So bars is colored red if they are definitely above this value (given the confidence interval), blue if they are definitely below, or white if they contain this value.
The finished plot contains too many xticks labels. I tried using a few methods like `xaxis.set_major_locator` and `plt.xticks(range(len(df.index)), df.index)` but it all turned out bad.
I think it's the problem with my color mask setting, but I cant figure how to fix it.

Really appreciate any help and advice. Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(12345)

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])

mean = df.mean(axis = 1)
std = df.std(axis = 1)
n = len(df.columns)

yerr = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    yerr.append(stats.sem(row)*stats.t.ppf((1+0.95)/2, n-1))

theline = 42000
high_mask = theline > (mean+yerr)
low_mask = theline < (mean-yerr)
equal_mask = ((mean-yerr) <= theline) & (theline <= (mean+yerr))

plt.figure()
plt.bar(df.index[high_mask.values], mean.iloc[high_mask.values], alpha=0.5, color='blue')
plt.bar(df.index[low_mask.values], mean.iloc[low_mask.values], alpha=0.5, color='red')
plt.bar(df.index[equal_mask.values], mean.iloc[equal_mask.values], alpha=0.5, color='grey')
plt.errorbar(df.index, mean, yerr=yerr, fmt=".", color="k")
plt.axhline(y=theline, color="grey", alpha=0.7)
# plt.gca().set_xticklabels(df.index)
# plt.xticks(range(len(df.index)), df.index)
plt.show()
```

[image: finish-plot]

Comment: this sould work `plt.xticks(df.index)`

Comment: thank you. this works for me too. dont know why I missed this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the x-ticks to a custom array of x-axis values using the `set_xticks` method of the axis object.

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks([1992, 1993, 1994, 1995])
```

[image]